# Does a Normal Moore paratopological group always have countable chain condition?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Does a Normal Moore paratopological group always have countable chain condition? Or is it separable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that an arbitrary uncountable discrete group is a counterexample. :-)